# Idea collection platform

Tags: untagged

I need a free webpage or -preferably- a deployable web application that allows me to collect ideas from multiple users. I remember checking out a feature-request platform but I cannot remember the URL or the name of the tool.

The users should be able to:

- Submit their ideas
- Vote on other people's ideas
- Discuss already added ideas
- Report abuse
- Less importantly see information like "Already accepted ideas", "Total ideas in the system", "Most discussed ideas"

The owner of the project should be able to:

- *All the things above*
- Remove submissions
- Moderate the content generated by the community

It is enough if you tell me how are these platforms called so I can research the topic myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Uservoice](http://uservoice.com) and [GetSatisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/) sound like the kind of service you are looking for.

[IdeaTorrent](http://drupal.org/project/ideatorrent) is another alternative, based on Drupal.

You can find many more options in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154967/customer-feedback-alternative-to-uservoice) on StackOverflow.